# Restful (or other) gateway/wrapper API for my android phone

Tags: android, api

Is there one app which can expose all of an android phone's native API over LAN?

There is at least one good app you can download which allows sending and receiving text messages via a restful API. But then, it's made by some other developer so I can't be 100% sure about the security. Furthermore, I want access to EVERYTHING, not just SMS.

I tried searching online, but there is nothing there or the search term combo is akin to brute forcing a password.

I want to be able to have fun mashing up desktop integration systems, via my language of choice.

I imagine the solution to be a service which runs on my phone, that will have full access to all phone functions, require secure API key. It will be on my desk, plugged into charger so I don't care about power efficiency (polling), but a dual-bindary model would be appealing (registering a callback endpoint, which is called upon phone event such as SMS received, or phone ringing etc..).

Any ideas? Do I need to make this myself?

Comment: Looks like I have to create my own, hackathon time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, not a single app solution, but here's what you can do:

- SMS - use SMS Gateway. This app will post to an HTTP server of your choice when an SMS arrives
- Accelerometer - use Wireless IMU. This app will send via UDP. This means you can maintain low-latency operation, dropped packets are lost forever. [See http://www.appszoom.com/android_applications/accelerometer+sensor+values+to+computer, for other app options]
- NFC - Not found
- Phone Calls - Not found
- Camera (Streaming) - Not Found
- Take Photo - Not found

Not Found - No open API app found for the specified purpose.

**Receiving accelerometer data - UDP**

```
class Inertia : IDisposable
{
    UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(5555);
    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5555);
    Control context = null;

    public Inertia(Control context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(udpCallback), null);
    }

    private void udpCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        byte[] data = listener.EndReceive(result, ref groupEP);

        if (data.Length > 0)
        {
            string line = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            if (context.InvokeRequired)
                context.BeginInvoke(UDPStringReceived, line);
            else
                if (UDPStringReceived != null) UDPStringReceived(line);
        }

        result = listener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(udpCallback), null);
    }

    public delegate void UDPStringReceivedHandler(string line);
    public event UDPStringReceivedHandler UDPStringReceived;


    public void Dispose()
    {
        //TODO: Stop listening
    }
}
```

**Using Inertia class for use with WinForms:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    Inertia inertia = null;
    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inertia = new Inertia(this);
        inertia.UDPStringReceived += inertia_UDPStringReceived;
    }

    void inertia_UDPStringReceived(string line)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] components = line.Split(',');

            //My text boxes, showing the data
            t.Text = components[0];
            //index 1 contains the value 2, which probably indicates "Accelerometer" in next 3 values
            aX.Text = components[2];
            aY.Text = components[3];
            aZ.Text = components[4];
            //index 5 contains the value 3, which probably indicates "Gyroscope" in next 3 values
            gX.Text = components[6];
            gY.Text = components[7];
            gZ.Text = components[8];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A practical example of what you could expect to have to do to trap the REST/Network call layer as System apps are doing their networking work ( its mostly Sync of media, Sync of messages)...

Say that you want to intercept the REST calls that the photo-gallery app makes as it syncs its media...

The network calls that wrap the HttpClient that relates to your Rest api are encapsulated in a very deep, and very proprietary stack that you can get an appreciation of [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery3D/blob/eclair/src/com/cooliris/cache/CacheService.java)

look there at 'loadMediaSets()', 'loadMediaSet()' and note that there is not an interface involving HttpClient or rest. The networking involves 'dataInputStreams' that are wrapped by a different ( non-Rest ) interface that you could not expect to observe or overload.

The passage of media across the network in the system apps is not worth trying to get at with a simple idea of a REST Api.

If you were to spend alot of time with the Android api, you could come up with a list of client side events like 'OnNewTextMessage' or something in the status bar. Again, that is going to be alot of low level work for each media type that you wish to intercept.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will make my question clearer, I understand that the native API is not RESTful or externalized in any way. I am wanting to know if there is an app which can wrap all the native APIs. I would expect most of it to be RESTful, but understand that other complimentary access may be required, particularly for media. (Although media isn't really my focus for now, but rather other services such as SMS, Phone, Orientation)